# Listview in scrollable layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Don't use listviews in scrollviews they say, well, okay, but how do you fix this?

I have a viewpager with some lists in it (mockup)
above that, I have a tabindicator and some other information that doesn't change when you go to another tab.

My problem is that I always want to scroll the complete view (so content, tabindicator and viewpager).
If you scroll down, only the fragment with the listview (=tab content) should be visible and scrollable.

I don't want to put the content view and tab headers in a listview header because I don't want them to change every time I go to another tab (swipey tabs, so the user will see it)

What's the best way to do this?

[image: Mockup]

Comment: If your list isn't terribly long, you could use a LinearLayout instead of a ListView.

Comment: I also thought about that, but I cannot guarantee the length of the lists, that's why I'm looking for a better solution (it's already implemented as a listadapter, but that's a minor issue)